# fallback server when one service provider goes down

Tags: cloud

How do I go about setting up a fallback server on a different service provider so that when my main one goes down traffic gets rerouted to the other? I have an RoR app running on Heroku and it was affected by the amazon outage and I want to figure out the best way to prevent downtime on my app. So I signed up for Rackspace and I'm setting that up now.

So how do I automatically switch from heroku to rackspace when heroku goes down or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a heartbeat monitor on your service or the service you are using - when it fails to respond, switch over.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot more complicated than that - your servers will be on different IP subnets as if they are with different providers so it's not simply a case of switching over.

There are two approaches to this - either you have a load balanced system where both are virtual machines are active and if one falls over then the remaining one takes on the full load. The other option is to have a backup machine that can be brought online in the event of a failure.

The later is the simplest method and from my experience I'd look at one of the VMware hosting providers as this functionality is pretty straightforward. Companies like [StratoGen](http://www.stratogen.net) can host a virtual machine in 2 different datacentres that are geographically diverse so although they are with the same provider there is very little chance of both datacentres going down at the same time. Hosting in this way makes it relatively simple to bring online the backup server, or indeed to have both running within a load balanced system.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it (in general) is setup a secondary architecture exactly similar to the first one on a different provider, it would be tricky to setup replication between providers so you'd most likely need to setup your own scripts for that, then I would have as Oded said a heartbeat monitor (a simple curl script would do) that would monitor the application on each of the servers, once the main server fails to respond (after a certain amount of acceptable time) the script would send a request to the DNS provider, switching the main domain name entry to match the IP of the secondary server.

Switching back to the first server would be even trickier because now your most recent data if on the secondary server, so replication would have to be inverted or manually restoring it to the main.

This is not an idea solution and there are many failure points, if anyone has a better or enhanced solution, I wanna know about it.